# Nested numbered lists in Ghost blog

Tags: markdown, ghost, commonmark

What's the proper syntax for creating nested numbered lists on Ghost. The docs only show the syntax for single numbered lists and the things I've tried didn't work:

````
```
 1. One
   1. NestedOne
 2. Two
```
````

Or:

````
```
 1. One
   1) NestedOne
 2. Two
```
````

Or:

````
```
 1. One

   1. NestedOne

 2. Two
```
````

It can't be this hard now, can it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh the trick sis to use more spaces!

````
```
 1. Test
    1. test
```
````